# If we represent the anchor link which is not in the same page then how to redirect to that link in JQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, anchor, external

To link a page which is within the same page or else outside the html page it may redirects 
to the particular link based on `<a>` link

**Here is the code for the html:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="main">
   <a href="pop.html" data-transition="slide">page1</a>
   <a href="#page2" data-transition="slide">page2</a>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
  this is page2
</div>
```

Here the page1 is external html file if we click that it is showing as **Loading Error page**

while page2 is in the same page so it redirects to it . Please give suggestions for this how to link a html which is *external*.

Comment: Can you write a better clarification of your question? Do you want to know how to open a specific page inside an another HTML file, or just another HTML file?

Answer (score 0):

From JQM Docs:

**Linking without Ajax**

Links that point to other domains or that have rel="external", data-ajax="false" or target attributes will not be loaded with Ajax. Instead, these links will cause a full page refresh with no animated transition. Both attributes (rel="external" and data-ajax="false") have the same effect, but a different semantic meaning: rel="external" should be used when linking to another site or domain, while data-ajax="false" is useful for simply opting a page within your domain from being loaded via Ajax. Because of security restrictions, the framework always opts links to external domains out of the Ajax behavior.